# AvalonEdit: Cascading HighlightingColorizers

Tags: c#, .net, avalonedit

I want to cascade the SyntaxHighlighting Engine of AvalonEdit. I have 2 `HighlightingDefinitions`. The first one is the main syntax. The second one is a complex multiline-preprocessor-markup-language. For this reason it is too complicated to embbed the second grammar in the first one. The easier way is to render the first syntax, and change the affected line-parts (based on the second syntax) afterwards.

So I instantiated a new `HighlightingColorizer` with the second language and added it to the `LineTransformers`. But the second language colorizes the complete document and not only the lineparts with the preprocessor-directives: the non-preprocessor-code is black.

As I debugged the `ColorizeLine`-method of the second line transformer, the lines of the non-highlighted code (= no preprocessor code) have not been colorized, as expected. But the color of the lines are black.

So does the `HighlightingColorizer` reset all previous highlighting of the whole document before it starts to colorize?

Or what else could be the problem? How can I properly cascade 2 `HighlightingColorizers`?

Comment: I've worked a bit with AvalonEdit- and IIRC it does reset all highlighting when you apply another colorizer. The best way around this would be to re-attempt to embed the second grammar within the first- failing that you would have to mess with AvalonEdit's codebase to change how it interprets and re-applies the color scheme. The latter would probably be non-trivial as I dont think its going to be as easy an 'commenting the reset' or something like that.

Comment: @Xeno is right here. You will definately have to edit the code base if you do not wish to use XML definition files. However, I am not sure why you would not want to do this - they can be as long as you want and can be used to colorize the smalled detail. I have just written a file to do a simalar thing with embedded SQL; it is fast and works well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `HighlightingColorizer` does not directly store a reference to the `DocumentHighlighter`, but instead stores it via `TextView.Services`. This is done to allow attaching the same colorizer to multiple editors, so that each editor gets its own `DocumentHighlighter`.

When you attach a second colorizer, it overwrites the `IHighlighter` stored in the service container; and both colorizers end up using the new highlighter.

Also, note that the 'copy to clipboard' logic in `HtmlClipboard` directly accesses the `IHighlighter` service, it does not use any colorizers. (copying text to Word preserves the syntax highlighting only, no other transformations like fold markers)

There are essentially two approaches to solve this issue:

1. Do not store the additional highlighter as a service. You can do this by creating your own copy of the `HighlightingColorizer` class, and use a field in that class instead of accessing `textView.Services`. This is an easy change, but additional highlighters will not be used when copying text to the clipboard.
2. Create an `IHighlighter` implementation that combines the `HighlightedLine`s from multiple `DocumentHighlighter`s. This is the approach we are using for the C# semantic highlighting in SharpDevelop 5, which works as an additional highlighter that extends the existing .xshd-based C# highlighting. However, this approach is complex (merging `HighlightedLine`s is non-trivial given the ordering and nesting constraints on the sections), and requires an API change to the `IHighlighter` interface in order to deal with the `OnHighlightStateChanged` notification (AvalonEdit 4.x uses a derived class nested in `HighlightingColorizer` to get access to this callback; AvalonEdit 5.0 will use an event).